# How to select only the first rows for each unique value of a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say I have a table of customer addresses:

```
+-----------------------+------------------------+
|         CName         |      AddressLine       |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
|  John Smith           |  123 Nowheresville     |
|  Jane Doe             |  456 Evergreen Terrace |
|  John Smith           |  999 Somewhereelse     |
|  Joe Bloggs           |  1 Second Ave          |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

In the table, one customer like John Smith can have multiple addresses.
I need the `SELECT` query for this table to return only first row found where there are duplicates in 'CName'. For this table it should return all rows except the 3rd (or 1st - any of those two addresses are okay but only one can be returned).

Is there a keyword I can add to the `SELECT` query to filter based on whether the server has already seen the column value before?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

A very simple answer if you say you don't care which address is used.

```
SELECT
    CName, MIN(AddressLine)
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY
    CName
```

If you want the first according to, say, an "inserted" column then it's a different query

```
SELECT
    M.CName, M.AddressLine,
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        CName, MIN(Inserted) AS First
    FROM
        MyTable
    GROUP BY
        CName
    ) foo
    JOIN
    MyTable M ON foo.CName = M.CName AND foo.First = M.Inserted
```

Comment: Though it may not be intended to be used this way when selecting 10 columns. Also seems it cannot accept a column of the bit type.

Comment: @nuit9: of course it won't work with bit and 10 columns. Neither of these facts is in your question. You'd use the 2nd technique or Ben Thul's technique. I answered what you asked specifically, with pointers on how to solve more generally.

Comment: The first part DO work with multiple columns, athough not with bit-type columns. I tested this in MS SQL server 2016 though.

Comment: This answer works for many database platforms.

Answer (score 50):

You can use the `row_number() over(partition by ...)` syntax like so:

```
select * from
(
select *
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CName ORDER BY AddressLine) AS rownum
from myTable
) as a
where rownum = 1
```

What this does is that it creates a column called `rownum`, which is a counter that increments every time it sees the same `CName`, and indexes those occurrences by `AddressLine`. By imposing `where rownum = 1`, one can select the `CName` whose `AddressLine` comes first alphabetically. If the `order by` was `desc`, then it would pick the `CName` whose `AddressLine` comes last alphabetically.

Comment: This has the added benefit of not restricting you to only the first row. In my case I was actually looking for the first 3 occurances as a means of sense checking. The last line would just be `where row < 4`

Comment: 'row' is a reserved word in mysql. I recommend a different variable on line 4 and 7

Answer (score 35):

In SQL 2k5+, you can do something like:

```
;with cte as (
  select CName, AddressLine,
  rank() over (partition by CName order by AddressLine) as [r]
  from MyTable
)
select CName, AddressLine
from cte
where [r] = 1
```

Comment: Please explain what does rank, partition and [r] do

Answer (score 8):

You can use `row_number()` to get the row number of the row. It uses the `over` command - the `partition by` clause specifies when to restart the numbering and the `order by` selects what to order the row number on. Even if you added an `order by` to the end of your query, it would preserve the ordering in the `over` command when numbering.

```
select *
from mytable
where row_number() over(partition by Name order by AddressLine) = 1
```

Comment: In postgresql, window functions are not allowed in WHERE clause

Comment: This is neither allowed for MS-SQL.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` doesn't work in `Where` clause in Teradata as well

Answer (score 4):

This will give you one row of each duplicate row. It will also give you the bit-type columns, and it works at least in MS Sql Server.

```
(select cname, address 
from (
  select cname,address, rn=row_number() over (partition by cname order by cname) 
  from customeraddresses  
) x 
where rn = 1) order by cname
```

If you want to find all the duplicates instead, just change the rn= 1 to rn > 1.
Hope this helps

Comment: I get SQL compilation error: error line 3 at position 25 invalid identifier 'RN' with this solution

Answer (score -2):

```sql
select amount 
from (
  select distinct(amount) 
  from orders 
  order by amount desc 
  limit 3
) 
order by amount asc 
limit 1;
```

Answer (score -5):

to get every unique value from your customer table, use

```
SELECT DISTINCT CName FROM customertable;
```

more in-depth of w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp