# Sort by time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select  
logs.uid,
logs.event_value

from publicview.treasurehunters_ok logs
left join public.app_ok_cbaiodclebabababa_agg_users users  on logs.uid=users.uid
where  first_event_time>='01.09.2017 0:00:00'
and first_event_time <= '11.09.2017 0:00:00'
and logs.event ='balance_OK'
```

I need to sort each uid by time in ascending order and leave only the first values for `logs.event_value`

I.e

```
uid  logs.event_value
1      10
1      5
1      3
```

we need to return only
`1 10` i.e. leave the  first lines
for each user. 
So it is possible to make?

Comment: Hint: `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: can you write more detaily, i am newby

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, it,s MS SQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select only the first rows for each unique value of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662464/how-to-select-only-the-first-rows-for-each-unique-value-of-a-column)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pick one id only, the one with max date right? You can run partition by, something like this:

```
select * from (
select  
logs.uid,
logs.event_value,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY first_event_time DESC) r 

from publicview.treasurehunters_ok logs
left join public.app_ok_cbaiodclebabababa_agg_users users  on 
logs.uid=users.uid
where  first_event_time>='01.09.2017 0:00:00'
and first_event_time <= '11.09.2017 0:00:00'
and logs.event ='balance_OK') tab
where r=1
```

Comment: Tnx, column reference "uid" is ambiguous. What's wrong

Comment: @D.Joe : Try `PARTITION BY logs.uid` or `PARTITION BY users.uid` .

Comment: yeah sorry PARTITION BY logs.uid ORDER BY first_event_time DESC

Comment: The reason is because more than one table in the jon has a uid and you have to specify which one to use. So logs.uid is one from table logs. Hope explanation helps

Comment: not max date, i need the first date where logs.event_value got the first value, so i am interested to know what the first value on logs.event_value has every user

Comment: so order asc (first date registered) instead. (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY first_event_time ASC)