# Remove duplicates in Select query based on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to select without duplicate `id`s and keep row `'5d'` and not `'5e'` in select statement.

table

```
id | name
1  | a
2  | b
3  | c
5  | d
5  | e
```

I tried:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM table t
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table) t2 ON t.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662464/how-to-select-only-the-first-rows-for-each-unique-value-of-a-column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Comment: Make sure to always specify what rule you want applied. " and keep row 5d and not 5e" only tells us that 'd' wins over 'e' and we don't know why. What if it were not 'd' and 'e' but 'a' and 'z' or whatever other name? Is 'd' better than 'e', because it comes before 'e' in the alphabet? Or because it is not a vowel? So, in case of duplicates: how to decide for the value to keep?

Comment: I want to keep the earliest insertion and remove the latest

Comment: Define "earliest"? By definition a table is an unordered set. That means you have to provide order with the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM (
    SELECT id, name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY name) rn 
    FROM mytable
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

This will retain the record that has the smallest `name` (so `'5d'` will come before `'5e'`). With this technique, you can also use a sort criteria on another column that the one where duplicates exists (which an aggregate query with `MIN()` cannot do). Also, queries using window functions *usually* perform better than the equivalent aggregate query.

Answer (score 6):

For the given example an aggregation using `min()` would work.

```
SELECT id,
       min(name) name
       FROM table
       GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the row with the smallest name then you can use `not exists`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where id = t.id and name < t.name
)
```

Comment: I am a little confused by this snippet, could you please a bit explain how it works?

Comment: @bentz123 this query selects only the rows of the tables for which there is no other row with the same `id` but less `name` (alphabetically). So it returns distinct ids with the least `name` of each id.