# Select just one row by date with JOIN

Tags: sql-server

I have these tables and I want to show this SELECT result

```
Fecha      Mes                  Dia                  Pendiente       Responsable
---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------- -------------
2019-03-31 Marzo                Domingo              NULL            NULL
2019-04-01 Abril                Lunes                Entrevista 5    Ricardo
2019-04-02 Abril                Martes               Entrevista 15   Ricardo
2019-04-03 Abril                Miercoles            NULL            NULL
2019-04-04 Abril                Jueves               Entrevista 41   Ricardo
```

These are the tables:

```
Calendario
fecha      mes         dia
---------- ----------- -----------
2019-03-31 3           7
2019-04-01 4           1
2019-04-02 4           2
2019-04-03 4           3
2019-04-04 4           4
2019-04-05 4           5
2019-04-06 4           6
2019-04-07 4           7
2019-04-08 4           1

Mes
mes         nombre
----------- --------------------
3           Marzo
4           Abril

Dia
dia         nombre
----------- --------------------
1           Lunes
2           Martes
3           Miercoles
4           Jueves
5           Viernes
6           Sabado
7           Domingo

Responsable
responsable nombre
----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           Ricardo
3           Alberto

Pendientes
fecha      responsable pendiente
---------- ----------- ----------------
2019-04-01 1           Entrevista 5
2019-04-04 1           Entrevista 42
2019-04-08 3           Entrevista 97
2019-04-04 1           Entrevista 48
2019-04-02 1           Entrevista 15
2019-04-01 3           Entrevista 8
2019-04-04 3           Entrevista 43
2019-04-04 1           Entrevista 41
```

I want just the first row by date, but I can't, here is my SQL syntax:

```
SELECT c.fecha as Fecha, m.nombre as Mes, d.nombre as Dia, p.pendiente as Pendiente, r.nombre as Responsable 
FROM pendientes p RIGHT OUTER JOIN calendario c ON p.fecha = c.fecha 
LEFT OUTER JOIN responsable r ON p.responsable = r.responsable 
INNER JOIN mes m ON m.mes = c.mes 
INNER JOIN dia d ON d.dia = c.dia 
WHERE c.fecha between '20190331' and '20190404'
```

When I run it show all values with same dates included.
I also tried with group by but with same results

Answer (score 0):

You can use next query:-

```
;with cte as (
  SELECT c.fecha as Fecha, m.nombre as Mes, d.nombre as Dia, p.pendiente as Pendiente, r.nombre as Responsable ,
  rank() over (partition by c.fecha order by p.pendiente) as [r]
FROM pendientes p RIGHT OUTER JOIN calendario c ON p.fecha = c.fecha 
LEFT OUTER JOIN responsable r ON p.responsable = r.responsable 
INNER JOIN mes m ON m.mes = c.mes 
INNER JOIN dia d ON d.dia = c.dia 
WHERE c.fecha between '20190331' and '20190404'
)
 SELECT  Fecha,  Mes,  Dia,  Pendiente,  Responsable 
from cte
where [r] = 1
```

also you can use `Group by` as next if you want a one row regardless its sort:-

```
SELECT c.fecha as Fecha, Min(m.nombre) as Mes, Min(d.nombre) as Dia, Min(p.pendiente) as Pendiente, Min(r.nombre) as Responsable 
FROM pendientes p RIGHT OUTER JOIN calendario c ON p.fecha = c.fecha 
LEFT OUTER JOIN responsable r ON p.responsable = r.responsable 
INNER JOIN mes m ON m.mes = c.mes 
INNER JOIN dia d ON d.dia = c.dia 
WHERE c.fecha between '20190331' and '20190404'
group by c.fecha
```

I Think, the first query is what you need.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4662499/1683270).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your output. This code is done on Mysql if you are using SQL Server then change "Limit" with "TOP".

```
 Select fecha,mes,Dia,pendiente,responsable from
    (Select fecha,mes,Dia,min(pendiente) as pendiente, responsable, 
    min(responsible)
    from (
    Select Q.*, E.nombre as Responsable
    from (Select A.fecha, B.nombre as mes, C.nombre as Dia, D.pendiente, 
    D.responsible 
    from Calendario A
    Left join
    (Select * from mes) B
    on A.mes=B.mes
    Left Join
    (Select * from Dia) C
    on A.dia=C.dia
    Left Join
    (Select * from Pendientes) D
    on A.fecha=D.fecha
    order by fecha
    )Q
    Left Join
    (Select * from Responsable) E
    on Q.responsible = E.resonable
    )Z group by fecha order by fecha limit 5
    )T
```