# Identifying first unique value in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `crashes` with around one million rows, each row containing data on either:

- every car crash that *did not* occur near a school, or
- every car crash that occurred near a school, with additional rows per crash if it occurred near more than one school (e.g. 4 rows for a crash near 4 schools). The highest number of rows/nearby schools for one crash is 10.

I'd like to add a column to the table returning a "1" for only one appearance of every crash_id that appears in more than one row, and a "0" for any subsequent occurrences of that same crash_id in the column `crash_id`. Which row has a 1 or 0 per crash_id doesn't matter.

I've tried all of the suggestions offered in response to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662464/how-to-select-only-the-first-rows-for-each-unique-value-of-a-column/4662671), but I couldn't get any of them to work for me.

FWIW, I got this to work in Excel using this formula:

```
=(COUNTIF($C$2:$C2,$C2)=1)+0
```

But that was for a small table, not one with one million rows.

What I've tried so far:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY crash_id) AS row 
    FROM crashes 
) AS A1 
WHERE row <6
```

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY crash_id) AS row 
    FROM crashes
) AS A1 
WHERE row = 1
```

I understand this isn't optimal database design, but it allows me to get most of what I need, except for what I'm describing above.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. Also note that homework related questions are expected to prove some extra effort.

Comment: "...for the first appearance of every unique crash_id..." -- How do you define which one of the 10 rows is the first one? Remember that in relational databases rows don't have injerent ordering.

Comment: First, this is a poor database design. There should be a `crash` table, and a `crash-at-school` table with `crash_id` as a foreign key. Repetitions of the `crash_id` value in the `crash` table is a code smell.

What is the unique key of the `crash` table? Without one, how will you identify the rows to be updated?

Comment: **jarlh** this isn't homework. If you're asking to see what I've tried so far:

'
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT *
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY crash_id) AS row
from crashes
) AS A1
WHERE row <6
'

'
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT *
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY crash_id) AS row
FROM joined
) as A1
WHERE row = 1
'

Comment: **TheImpaler** for my purposes it doesn't really matter which one is identified as first. I just want a column that will allow me to filter the table so that I only see one row per crash (i.e. WHERE id_unique = '1').

Comment: **Andrew Lazarus** Fair enough (I'm new to this). I created this table by joining a prior table `crashes` with a table `schools`, so there's nothing wrong with the data. Having the data organized this way enables me to get nearly everything I need from it, except for the column I'm seeking in my original question. There's also a primary key column with a unique number for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple test to add a first_crash column to crashes.

But it needs something to determine which row was first.  Since tables are in essence unsorted sets.
The example uses the ID for that.

> ```
> create table crashes (
>  id serial primary key, 
>  crash_id int, 
>  school_id int
> );
>
> alter table crashes 
>   add constraint uniq_school_crash unique (crash_id, school_id);
>
> insert into crashes (crash_id, school_id) values
>   (101,11), (101,10), (101,12)
> , (102,25), (102,24), (102,23)
> , (103,null)
>
> alter table crashes
>  add column first_crash int default 0;
> ```

> ```
> update crashes c
> set first_crash = 1
> where first_crash = 0
>   and ( 
>        school_id is null
>     or not exists (
>       select 1
>       from crashes c2
>       where c2.crash_id = c.crash_id
>         and c2.id < c.id
>     ));
> ```

> ```
> select * from crashes order by id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | crash_id | school_id | first_crash
> -: | -------: | --------: | ----------:
>  1 |      101 |        11 |           1
>  2 |      101 |        10 |           0
>  3 |      101 |        12 |           0
>  4 |      102 |        25 |           1
>  5 |      102 |        24 |           0
>  6 |      102 |        23 |           0
>  7 |      103 |      null |           1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=207419934f7fc7ef3956c3052794799a)*

**Extra**

1. update by row_number

```
-- using row_number
update crashes c
set first_crash = q.rn
from ( 
      select id
      , row_number() over (partition by crash_id 
                           order by id asc) as rn
      from crashes
) q
where q.rn = 1 
  and q.id = c.id;
```

2. using a temp table

```
-- using temporary table
create temporary table tmp_crashes (
 id int primary key, 
 crash_id int
);

insert into tmp_crashes (id, crash_id)
select min(id), crash_id
from crashes
group by crash_id
order by min(id);

update crashes t
set first_crash = 1
from tmp_crashes tmp
where tmp.id = t.id;
```

Comment: I tried this on my dataset and it was taking hours to execute. Any idea why / how to speed it up? Could it be that 1m-row dataset is too large for a query like this?

Comment: What are the indexes on the table?

Comment: I don't have any...

Comment: That's probably one reason why it's slow, no matter what sql trick you use.

Comment: OK, I'll have to learn about how to add indexes then. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AenidMansarde Just for fun, added 2 extra methods to the fiddle.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I'll have to spend some time understanding these.