# How to select only one row for each unique id, with other columns having certain condition value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two columns one the 'clientID' and the second 'usable'. A clientID can appear several times in my table.

If only one occurrence of this clientID exists with a 'NO' it means that in my final table it will have to be tagged 'NO'.

If it has only occurrences with 'YES' it means that it will be tagged in my final table with 'YES'.

how i can make this final table ?

```
CREATE TABLE InitialValues (
    idClient varchar(5),
    usable varchar(3),
);


insert into InitialValues(idClient,usable) values
('c1234','yes'),
('c1334','yes'),
('c1334','no'),
('c1434','yes');

select * from InitialValues


CREATE TABLE FinalValues (
    idClient varchar(5),
    usable varchar(3),
);


insert into FinalValues(idClient,usable) values
('c1234','yes'),
('c1334','no'),
('c1434','yes');

select * from finalValues
```

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b89b304198727e8794817036b15fc80c)

Comment: now that your question is answered, can you please edit it so that it becomes a generic enough question, so that it can potentially help a wider audience in future. E.g. you can take direction from [this question: click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662464/how-to-select-only-the-first-rows-for-each-unique-value-of-a-column)

Comment: E.g. At minimum, You can just edit the title to something like: How to select only one row for each unique id, with other columns having certain value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it without creating a second `FinalValues` table. You can select from `InitialValues` in such a way that you don't have to create a redundant table.

```
SELECT idClient, usable FROM
(
SELECT *
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY idClient ORDER BY usable) AS row
FROM InitialValues
) as a
WHERE row = 1
```

What it does is that it sorts the rows by `usable` column. So that rows with `no` will come on the top. And then it selects first row only for each id. Ofcourse, each id's first row will have `usable` column as `no` if there was one for that id. If that `id` did not have any `no` only then there will be `yes`

However, if you still want to create a second table for some other requirement. You can still do so, and `Insert` the resultset of above `select` query into second table.