# How to select only the first rows for each combination of a set of columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found this article helpful: [How to select only the first rows for each unique value of a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662464/how-to-select-only-the-first-rows-for-each-unique-value-of-a-column)

However, it did not fully cover my requirements. To be honest, I don't think I fully understood the purpose / how to use the partition statement.

Starting with this MS SQL Table, I'd like to select the latest date for each File/Device combination.

```
+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|         Date          |          File          |         Device         |
+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|  09/09/2022           |  Acrobat.exe           |         ABC123         |
|  09/10/2022           |  Acrobat.exe           |         DEF456         |
|  11/07/2021           |  Visio.exe             |         ABC123         |
|  12/31/2020           |  Acrobat.exe           |         ABC123         |
+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

I wrapped my head around this for a while now and the only thing I could come up with was

```
with cte as (
    SELECT Date, File, Device, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Device order by File, Date DESC) as [r]
    FROM MyTable
)
select Date, File, Device, from cte WHERE [r] = 1
```

However, this will not always return exactly what I need. I'm not quite sure why but I think because it's only taking the change of one column into consideration for the row number to increase it's value.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I'd like to select the latest date for each File/Device combination.`
So you mean something like this ?

```
select max(t.mydate) as [date],
       t.myfile,
       t.device
from   mytable t
group by t.myfile, t.device
order by t.myfile
```

See this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/v89-7ip1)

the result is

| date | myfile | device |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-09 | Acrobat.exe | ABC123 |
| 2022-09-10 | Acrobat.exe | DEF456 |
| 2021-11-07 | Visio.exe | ABC123 |

Answer (score 1):

> I think because it's only taking the change of one column into
> consideration

Right, because that's what you asked for in the `over()` clause. Specifically, `partition by Device`. Given your requirement for "select the latest date for each File/Device combination", your definition for the r column in your CTE should look like:

```sql
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by File, Device order by Date DESC) as [r]
```