# How to remove duplicate entries from json string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I've checked stackoverflow as well as google but could not find any solution. What would be the proper way to remove duplicate entries from an nvarchar field that contains json string in SQL Server? For my case, let say I have nvarchar 'People' field on my table which contains the following data.

```
[
 {
  "name":"Jon",
  "age": 30
 },
 {
  "name":"Bob",
  "age": 30
 },
 {
  "name":"Nick",
  "age": 40
 },
 {
  "name":"Bob",
  "age": 40
 }
]
```

I need to remove the entries which has duplicate names which would be the 'Bob' in that case. So after executing the query I am expecting this result

```
[
 {
  "name":"Jon",
  "age": 30
 },
 {
  "name":"Bob",
  "age": 30
 },
 {
  "name":"Nick",
  "age": 40
 }
]
```

What would be the proper sql query to do that? Actually I am trying to achieve no duplicate names rather than no duplicate entries. That's why 2 Bobs have different ages in the above example. More specifically I need to keep only first items among duplicates for this example the first Bob with age 30.Using ROW_NUMBER() and Partition By would be solution but it breaks the existing order.I need to achieve this without breaking the existing order. So I have the table with Id and PeopleJson fields. The following query would achieve what I want to achieve but it breaks the order in PeopleJson

```
SELECT Id, (
    SELECT [Name],[Age] FROM (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY (select NULL)) as row_num
        FROM OPENJSON(PeopleJson) WITH ([Name] NVARCHAR(1000), [Age]  int)
    ) t WHERE t.row_num = 1
    FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
) as [People]
 From [TestTable]
```

Comment: Please update with the specific code you tried and the challenge it presents you.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I've updated the question with specific code example

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT value
    FROM OPENJSON(@json)
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

```sql
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[{"id": 1, "name": "Alice"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Bob"}, {"id": 1, "name": "Alice"}]'

SELECT (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT value
        FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    ) cte
    FOR JSON AUTO
) AS result
```

```json
[{"id":1,"name":"Alice"},{"id":2,"name":"Bob"}]
```

Comment: I need to eliminate duplicates based on a column value not the whole row value. If the 3rd 'Alice' will have different id then it won't eliminate the duplicates

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Can you provide some more information, please? I understand what you're trying to do, but I have some questions.

Each Bob has a different age, so those aren't duplicate entries, only duplicate names. Either way, it would be hard to decide which entry to remove if each one is different.

You can achieve no duplicate "Bob" entries, but the issue comes in when deciding which Bob record you want to keep.

Comment: Actually I am trying to achieve just no duplicate names rather than no duplicate entries

Comment: I am trying to keep first Bob

Comment: Can you query the whole table and deal with the duplicate Bobs in your controller? That might be easier that doing it in a SQL query.

For example, your return all People and then loop through those people and  when you hit the duplicates, don't use that entry.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to do this on T-SQL

Comment: In that case, I think you might find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662464/how-to-select-only-the-first-rows-for-each-unique-value-of-a-column

Comment: More of a comment than an answer